# Getting resources by different columns in Recess

Tags: php, web-services, rest, recess

I'm fairly new to RESTful web services and even more new to the Recess PHP framework. It's easy to retrieve resources by ID. For example, if I want to retrieve a User with ID 7, I would make a request to:

`http://localhost/myApp/user/7`

What I'm wondering is this: is there an easy way to retrieve a resource by a different column, for example, a user's username?

`http://localhost/myApp/user/username/tyler`

This seems like it would be something pretty important for a RESTful framework to have, so I'm guessing there's a way to do this or a way to implement it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this using the framework's parametric routing system. I created a function that can retrieve a User resource by a specified property value:

```
/** !Route GET, $property/$value */
function getUser($property, $value) {   
    $this->user = Make::a('User')->equal($property, $value)->first();  
}
```